# Connectionstring doesn't work for Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, azure, connection-string

I've been looking for this and haven't found a decent answer. 
It's about my connectionstring in my web.config of my ASP.NET MVC application
This is my connectionstring:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:****.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=***;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=****;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I also have a second, which works perfectly:

```
<add name="treinsqlEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TreinDB.csdl|res://*/TreinDB.ssdl|res://*/TreinDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*****.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=*****;user id=*****;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

It works perfectly on localhost, but it doesn't online, (The database and site is hosted on Azure) so the pasword and username are definitly correct.

I use this connectionstring to log in/register, sign up, ...

What's the problem?

Huge thank you in advance to all you lifesavers!

Edit: This is the exception:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fomoh.png)

These are my firewall settings: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi1ek.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is likely because you have not opened the firewall up to all azure connections.  By default there are no firewall rules added to your new databases/server in Azure.  You have probably added your local client IP but not checked the box that is for all Azure connections.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#overview The section 'Connecting from Azure' should point you to the right setting.

Please be aware that this allows all IP's originating from Azure a connection into you DB.  It does not allow access since your authentication mechanism will stop that but connections will be allowed from any subscription in Azure with this option checked.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response! I did what you told me to do, but it still doesn't work. I've placed everything on 0.0.0.0 and I'm still getting this error: Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'null'

Comment: Can you double check with me here that you went into the firewall settings for the DB and checked 'Allow access to Azure services'.  If that is the case then if the connection string is getting to Azure you should be good.  If it isn't please check your deployment wizard, look on the 'settings' tab and double check that you are actually sending up those connection strings you defined locally with your deployment.

Comment: I editted my questions with some pictures, could you please be kind enough to check them out?

Comment: You look all set on the firewall side.  At this point the second most common problem is that you aren't sending up your connection strings to your azure site.  Especially since it says your username is null.  Please double check your deployment and then go to the portal and double check under your App Service -> Application Settings section that the connection string is actually making it to your cloud hosting slot (I am assuming app service plan hosting)

Comment: Now it works like a charm! I can't thank you enough! I'll make sure to let you know our grades on this schoolproject ;)